# ACCEDER A LAS PROPIEDADES DEL CHART DESDE EL CÓDIGO C# VISUAL STUDIO 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Cómo puedo acceder a la propiedad del **Chart** (en el apartado de **Series**/Gráfico/ChartType) desde el código? (*NO* desde el modo diseño).

El software se está desarrollando en lenguaje C# en Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Te falta agregar tu codigo que estas trabajando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para acceder al tipo de serie de un chart puedes hacerlo del siguiente modo mediante código:

```
 chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta propiedad determina el tipo de gráfico del Series objeto; el valor distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. Vea la enumeración SeriesChartType para obtener una lista de todos los tipos de gráficos posibles para una serie.

Comment: La respuesta debe ir acompañada de codigo para que sea valida.